# Selecting a Cell based on Row and Column Headers, and Inputting a Value From an Input Section on that Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a Table from the range A112:H206, with *days of the week* (sunday, monday, etc) heading the table row from B112-H112. In column A, I have *names* of individuals listed going all the way down to A206.

I have an input section at the top of the spreadsheet, where a user will select a *name* from a drop down menu in cell A109, a *day of the week* from a drop down menu in cell B2, and finally a *value* in cell C109 which should be inputted in the corresponding cell in the table.

I created a button named "Enter" to which upon clicking should search for the corresponding cell based on the input section above, and input the C109 Value in that cell. Unfortunately my attempts using VBA were unsuccessful! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Range

    Dim valX, valY

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    valX = ws1.Range("B2").Value
    Set x = ws1.Range("A112:H112").Find(What:=valX, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        lookat:=xlWhole)

    If x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'" & valX & "' not found on '" & ws1.Name & "' !"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    valY = ws1.Range("A109").Value
    Set y = ws1.Range("A112:A206").Find(What:=valY, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not y Is Nothing Then
        Range("C109").Select
        Selection.Copy

        ws1.Cells(x.Column, y.Row).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Range("C109").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

        Exit Sub
    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Find()` to locate each of the required column/row "header" cells, then from those identify the "intersect" cell where the data needs to go.

Comment: If you have existing code you should add it to your question - doesn't have to actually work.

Comment: Ah unfortunately I got kinda frustrated and started from scratch; I suppose I need to brush up on the Find() function!

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477168/vba-loop-through-range-moving-values-dynamically-to-intersect-of-two-reference-p/20477527#20477527

Comment: Thank you! I will try to apply the answer there to my issue!

Comment: I think I might be just off on how to use the isect function: Here's what I have so far! (edited the Question)

Comment: Closer! I few minor edits to the references and such. What I am trying to do though is have the input value in "C109" be copied and pasted at the Intersection of ValX and ValY... Not sure if this is in the right direction (Edited once again!)

Comment: That's exactly what the code in my answer should do.  Did you try it as posted?

Comment: Ah yes, I did. Unfortunately, it simply cleared the C109 Field and never pasted that value in the table in the corresponding table.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help Tim, It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem - I did fix the error in my original answer, but it looks like you have a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped, I wanted to post it here just for reference for others!

```
Range("C109").Select
Selection.Copy

Dim Day As String
Dim Name As String
Dim nameFound As Boolean
Dim dayFound As Boolean

Name = Cells(109, "A").Value
Day = Cells(2, "B").Value

Range("A113").Select
nameFound = False
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If ActiveCell.Value = Name Then
        nameFound = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

If nameFound = True Then
    Dim nameAddress As Integer
    nameAddress = ActiveCell.Row
Else
    MsgBox "Name not found"
End If

Range("B112").Select
dayFound = False
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If ActiveCell.Value = Day Then
        dayFound = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop

If dayFound = True Then
    Dim dayAddress As Integer
    dayAddress = ActiveCell.Column
Else
    MsgBox "Day not found"
End If



Cells(nameAddress, dayAddress).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
If ActiveCell.Column = 2 Or ActiveCell.Column = 4 Or ActiveCell.Column = 6 Or ActiveCell.Column = 8 Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(83, 142, 213)

    ElseIf ActiveCell.Column = 3 Or ActiveCell.Column = 5 Or ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(182, 221, 232)
End If



Range("C109").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Range

    Dim valX, valY

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    valX = ws1.Range("A109").Value
    Set x = ws1.Range("A112:H112").Find(What:=valX, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        lookat:=xlWhole)

    If x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'" & valX & "' not found on '" & ws1.Name & "' !"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    valY = ws1.Range("B2").Value
    Set y = ws1.Range("A112:A206").Find(What:=valY,LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not y Is Nothing Then
        With ws1.Range("C109")
            .Copy ws1.Cells(y.Row, x.Column)' <<EDITED
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Name '" & valY & "' not found on '" & ws1.Name & "' !"
    End If

End Sub
```